# R error HTML is deprecated when scraping table from website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from a website:

I am using the following code:

```
library("rvest")

url <- "http://sabap2.birdmap.africa/coverage/pentad/2945_3100"

population <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="coverage_species"]/div/div/table') %>%
  html_table()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Warning message:
'html' is deprecated.
Use 'xml2::read_html' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
```

Can anyone suggest the correct approach using xml2?
I am also unsure if I have used the correct xPath in the html_nodes step?

Thank you

Comment: it is not an error, just a friendly warning.  If you  don't want to get the warning, usse `read_html` instead of `html` in the code

Comment: @akrun that's right, but the code doesn't work anyway because it's a dynamic webpage that requires a bit of low level work to scrape.

Comment: I haven't tested that, my comment was based on the warning itself

Comment: Perhaps it requires selenium

Comment: @akrun, no, it can be done with text parsing - see my answer

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, I had seen it.  I was thinking that it could be done more easily. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table you are looking for is built dynamically from Javascript after the page loads in your browser. You can extract the relevant pieces of Javascript using string manipulation and parse them to build the table in R.

This is nothing to do with the warning you got, which is just telling you to use `read_html()` instead of `html()` because `read_html()` is the newer function that does a similar job and `html()` is being phased out.

```r
url       <- "http://sabap2.birdmap.africa/coverage/pentad/2945_3100"
page      <- httr::content(httr::GET(url), "text")
json      <- strsplit(strsplit(page, "summarydata.addRows[(]")[[1]][2], "[)]")[[1]][1]
df        <- data.frame(rbind(jsonlite::fromJSON(json)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lines     <- strsplit(page, "[\r\n]+")[[1]]
linelist  <- strsplit(grep("summarydata[.]addCol", lines, value = TRUE), "'")
names(df) <- sapply(linelist, `[`, 4)
```

This gives the result in a nice data frame:

```
df
#>        Year no cards 1 card 2 cards 3 cards 4 or more Pentads covered
#> 1  AllYears        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 2      2020        0      0       0       1         0               1
#> 3      2019        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 4      2018        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 5      2017        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 6      2016        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 7      2015        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 8      2014        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 9      2013        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 10     2012        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 11     2011        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 12     2010        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 13     2009        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 14     2008        0      0       0       0         1               1
#> 15     2007        0      0       0       0         1               1
#>    Pentads in area Total Cards (FP) Total species (FP)
#> 1                1              361                284
#> 2                1                3                 44
#> 3                1               18                158
#> 4                1               21                165
#> 5                1               51                172
#> 6                1               45                198
#> 7                1               25                178
#> 8                1               12                149
#> 9                1               26                165
#> 10               1               34                163
#> 11               1               46                189
#> 12               1               36                181
#> 13               1               22                146
#> 14               1               17                173
#> 15               1                5                131
```

---

**Addendum**

The OP has asked for a different table to be parsed on the page. It can be done in a similar manner, like this:

```
species_json <- strsplit(page, "carddataspeciesmonthly[.]addRows[(]")[[1]][2]
species_tab <- jsonlite::fromJSON(strsplit(species_json, "[)];")[[1]][1])
species_df <- as.data.frame(species_tab)
species_cols <- strsplit(page, "carddataspeciesmonthly[.]addColumn[(]")[[1]][-1]
names(species_df) <- sapply(strsplit(species_cols, "'"), `[`, 4)
```

The resultant data frame is too large to show here, so I'll present it as a `tibble`:

```
dplyr::as_tibble(species_df)
# A tibble: 284 x 20
   Ref   Common_group Common_species Genus Species Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul  
   <fct> <fct>        <fct>          <fct> <fct>   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1 8     Albatross    Black-browed   Thal~ melano~ 0     0     0     0     0     0     3.2  
 2 1079  Albatross    Indian Yellow~ Thal~ carteri 0     0     0     0     0     0     3.2  
 3 4150  Albatross    Shy            Thal~ cauta   0     0     0     0     0     0     3.2  
 4 622   Apalis       Bar-throated   Apal~ thorac~ 22    31.8  38.9  33.3  30.8  46.7  38.7 
 5 625   Apalis       Yellow-breast~ Apal~ flavida 9.8   9.1   22.2  11.1  12.8  26.7  16.1 
 6 432   Barbet       Acacia Pied    Tric~ leucom~ 0     0     0     0     2.6   0     0    
 7 431   Barbet       Black-collared Lybi~ torqua~ 63.4  77.3  72.2  50    89.7  73.3  67.7 
 8 439   Barbet       Crested        Trac~ vailla~ 14.6  40.9  38.9  16.7  25.6  13.3  9.7  
 9 433   Barbet       White-eared    Stac~ leucot~ 17.1  18.2  11.1  44.4  35.9  40    35.5 
10 672   Batis        Cape           Batis capens~ 2.4   13.6  11.1  5.6   0     0     0    
# ... with 274 more rows, and 8 more variables: Aug <fct>, Sep <fct>, Oct <fct>, Nov <fct>,
#   Dec <fct>, RepRate <fct>, Records <fct>, Cards <fct>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much. I wanted to check one more thing. If you navigate to the link [link](http://sabap2.birdmap.africa/coverage/pentad/2945_3100) and scroll down. you'll see the table you produced above under "full protocol summary", is it possible to print the table that is displayed when you click on the "Species List" tab? That is ideally the table I'd like to be able to scrape. Thanks again

Comment: I tried changing the json line to `json      <- strsplit(strsplit(page, "carddataspecies.addRows[(]")[[1]][2], "[)]")[[1]][1]` but I get the following error when I run the df line `Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       [                 [8,"Albatross`